# Updating child and grandchild

Tags: apex

I have code which will update all of the grandchildren of a record. It works successfully but for some reason I am unable to get it to update the child as well (parent to the grandchild).

Here is the updated code in which I tried to use SET for the Contract_Terms__c (child) portion of the code instead of a list as an attempt to be able to set the values of the child as well as the grandchild :

I am unable to save this currently because I am getting the following error :

" Variable does not exist: Lsttask at line 9 column 13"

```
    trigger UpdateGrandchild on Contract_Overview__c (after update) {          

    for(Contract_Overview__c prj: trigger.new)
    {   

        if(trigger.oldmap.get(prj.Id).Contract_Status__c!=trigger.newmap.get(prj.Id).Contract_Status__c){  

            Set<Contract_Terms__c> toUpdate = new Set<Contract_Terms__c>();   
            Lsttask = new Set<Contract_Terms__c>([Select id,Contract_Title__c,TestField__c from Contract_Terms__c where Contract_Title__c=: prj.Id]);      

            for(Contract_Terms__c thistask: Lsttask)
            {      

                thistask.TestField__c = prj.Contract_Status__c;  

                if(!toUpdate.contains(thisTask)){
                    Lsttask.add(thistask);  
                }  


                List<Amendment__c> lstRc=[select id,TestField__c from Amendment__c where Contract_Terms__c =:thistask.id];

                Set<Amendment__c> RcToupdate=new Set<Amendment__c>();

                for(Amendment__c thisRc:lstRc)     
                {      

                    thisRc.TestField__c=prj.Contract_Status__c;  
                    RcToupdate.add(thisRc);     
                }

                if(!RcToupdate.isempty()){ 
                    update RcToupdate; 
                } 

            }

        } 

    }

}
```

Does anybody know what the problem is here ?

Thank you very much for your time & help in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [General trigger bulkification - best practices](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47469/general-trigger-bulkification-best-practices)

Comment: @ChristianDeckert - While there are bulkification issues the OP is having a different issue at this time.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe use a `SET` and check the list *before* adding elements too it and calling update on it, if order isn't particularly important, like so:

```
Set<Contract_Terms__c> Lsttask=new Set<Contract_Terms__c>();   
Lsttask = [Select id,Contract_Title__c,TestField__c from Contract_Terms__c where Contract_Title__c=: prj.Id];      
for(Contract_Terms__c thistask: Lsttask)
   {      
    {      
     thistask.TestField__c = prj.Test_For_Update__c;  
    system.debug('thisTask = '+thisTask);
    if(!Lsttask.contains(thisTask){
          system.debug('Adding to Lsttask list');
                   Lsttask.add(thistask);  
    }  
}
```

Updated code that should compile:

```
trigger UpdateGrandchild on Contract_Overview__c (after update) {          

    for(Contract_Overview__c prj: trigger.new)
    {   

        if(trigger.oldmap.get(prj.Id).Contract_Status__c!=trigger.newmap.get(prj.Id).Contract_Status__c){  

            Set<Contract_Terms__c> toUpdate = new Set<Contract_Terms__c>();   
            List<Contract_Terms__c> Lsttask = [Select id,Contract_Title__c,TestField__c from Contract_Terms__c where Contract_Title__c=: prj.Id];      

            for(Contract_Terms__c thistask: Lsttask)
            {      

                thistask.TestField__c = prj.Contract_Status__c;  

                if(!toUpdate.contains(thisTask)){
                    Lsttask.add(thistask);  
                }  


                List<Amendment> lstRc=[select id,TestField__c from Amendment__c where Contract_Terms__c =:thistask.id];

                Set<Amendment__c> RcToupdate=new Set<Amendment__c>();

                for(Amendment__c thisRc:lstRc)     
                {      

                    thisRc.TestField__c=prj.Contract_Status__c;  
                    RcToupdate.add(thisRc);     
                }

                if(!RcToupdate.isempty()){ 
                    update RcToupdate; 
                } 

            }

        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Jordan : I have substituted the SET feature for the LIST as you suggested but I am now getting the following error : "Compile Error: Illegal assignment from LIST<Contract_Terms__c> to SET<Contract_Terms__c> ". I've updated my original post to show the code as it stands now. I don't understand why I'm getting this since I do not refer to Contract_Terms__c as a LIST now. Can you help me on this ? Thank you very much. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Essentially the `SET` data-structure should let you do a simple check for a matching object in the set so that you don't get duplicates of the same id. Go ahead and add some `system.debug` statements and see where the item is getting added again

Comment: But as it is now I can't even save the code. I changed all of the LIST to SET, thinking that would solve the problem of duplicates but now I'm getting this error : "Compile Error: Illegal assignment from LIST<Contract_Terms__c> to SET<Contract_Terms__c> at line 9 column 13".

I don't understand why I'm getting that if I've taken out all references to LIST. I'm obviously doing something wrong here & I apologize for the rookie mistakes & questions. I really appreciate the help Jordan.

Comment: I've copied your code and initialized the `LIST` properly, you were reassigning the set you planned to update to the list. The 2nd operation, on `Amendment__c` you were closer to the goal - create a `SET` of items to be updated, and query a `LIST` of items to check, and add them to the update `SET` if they aren't already in there and fit the criteria.

Comment: @Zoom_v Queries return `List` collections. At line 9 you are assigning a `List` of records to a variable which is defined as a `Set`, this is the cause of the error. The `Set` has a constructor which takes a `List` as a parameter. You could modify line 9 as `Lsttask = new Set<Contract_Terms__c>([Select id,Contract_Title__c,TestField__c from Contract_Terms__c where Contract_Title__c=: prj.Id]);` which will get around the error, but as @Mohith suggested - the query at line 23 which is within the `for` loop is bad practice and should be moved outside of the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much Jordan - and Mark too ! I really appreciate both the help and the patience. I know I ask a lot of rookie questions.

Comment: @jordan.baucke - I may have spoken too soon. I am unable to save that code as well. The error I am getting is "DML requires SObject or SObject list type: SET<Amendment__c> at line 33 column 21", which is update statement. Also - won't I also need an update statement for lsttask as well ? Do you have an idea on this ? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hey Zoom_v I think that was a typo on my part...should be Amendment__c if you copied and pasted it directly. It was just meant to be pseudo-code, not a working implementation, just to give you an idea of what I was getting at. And I think you should simplify things if your having trouble, start with settings up the `list` from the query, than using a `system.debug` to review getting them into a `set`, than making a change, using `system.debug` again, and finally updating. Do this for one type *before* you try to cascade it.

Comment: @MarkPond - I applied the changes to that one line which you provided but I am now getting a "variable does not exist" error. I've updated my original post to show. I don't know how to declare the List beforehand because that will create the same error I had before. Can you please help with this ? I also think I will be seeing more of the same type of errors in the 2nd part of the code in which there are new LIST and SET being declared for the 2nd record to be updated, but I'm not sure since I can't get this to save.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: @Zoom_v, you are receiving that error because you removed the line where you declared the variable (as a Set). `Set<Contract_Terms__c> Lsttask = new Set<Contract_Terms__c>();`

Answer (score 3):

Whats most important is remove query from for loop .You have added query inside for loop and hence its possible to collect duplicate Ids

Bulkify with using sets and maps .

Comment: Thank you very much Mohith. If I knew how to do that and make it work I would go about doing it. Thanks again.